# Firebase. Is there way to ignore calling childAdded on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm listing data with childAdded observer in iOS. I understand this is Firebase design and it is called at first time to list data and when data is added.

I dont't want to call childAdded when data is added.
I'm having idea FEventTypeValue can not be call when list data.(is it correct?)

My question:

Is there way to ignore childAdded only when data is added or to list data at first time without childAdded?

Sorry for my English. Thanks for Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [iOS/OS X Quick Start](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-quickstart.html) uses this example. Essentially, you're just grabbing the entire value of the path rather than watching it for child events:

```
// Read data and react to changes
[f observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", snapshot.name, snapshot.value);
}];
```

To receive the value only once, instead of each time there is a change, you can utilize the observeSingleEventOfType method:

```
// Read data and react to changes
[f observeSingleEventOfType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
  NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", snapshot.name, snapshot.value);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you Kato. "for (FDataSnapshot* childSnap in snapshot.children)" is what I need to know! I didn't notice it. I should read reference more carefully.. Thanks a lot!